# how to remove the pickerview with out using ok or cancel button in iphone

Tags: iphone

Im new to iphone development. here in my application i added pickerview for some image categories. my problem is displaying pickerview but how to remove the pickerview when i click in view automaticaly it was dismiss.i added this code also [pickerview remove fromsuperview].

can any one plz help me about my problem for how to remove the pickerview programmaticaly in iphone.

thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

in your picker's parent view controller